# In angular how to implement *ngIf with If .. then.. else condition inside a <td> tag?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have tried to show the if else condition inside  block of table using ngIf but i am not able to display it.

```
  <tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
<!--here i need to implement it-->
   <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup"; then 
   [ngStyle]="titleStyles else [ngStyle]="oldStyles1">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
   <td>{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
   <td>{{client.name}}</td>
   <td>{{client.address}}</td>
   <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="titleStyles">Edit
   Delete</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

else and then can only used on ng-templates if you want conditional styles you could use ngClass or just add a single class using `[class.someClass] ="condition"` or manipulate the style using `[style.'some property']` since you're using ngStyle try this
in your component.ts you can have a function that returns your style depending on conditions such as your `!client.auditorGroup`

```
getStyle(value) { 
if(!value)
  return this.titleStyles;
}else {
  return this.oldStyles1;
}
```

and then in your component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let client of clients">
<!--here i need to implement it-->
   <td 
   [ngStyle]="getStyle(client.auditorGroup)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectionDate}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectedBy}}</td>
   <td>{{client.panEximNumber}}</td>
   <td>{{client.name}}</td>
   <td>{{client.address}}</td>
   <td>{{client.phoneNumber}}</td>
   <td>{{client.selectionType}}</td>
   <td [ngStyle]="getStyle(client.auditorGroup)">Edit
   Delete</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: u missed passing client to getStyle() ;) anyway i made according to your logic. Its working and fyn thnks

Comment: @ashwinkarki ah yea thanks for pointing that out. I just fixed it. I'm glad I was able to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide a reference to a template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td *ngIf="show; else tpl">A</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle</button>

<ng-template #tpl><td>Else template</td></ng-template>
```

If you want to toggle the style based on the condition, you can use a method:

```
<td [ngStyle]="calcStyles(client.auditorGroup)">{{client.selectionId}}</td>

calcStyles(auditorGroup) {
  if(auditorGroup) {
    return { color: 'red' }
  }

  return { color: 'green' }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ngClass] & conditionally assign to keep it simple.

NgClass logically groups css prop's together which is neat.

```
<td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngClass]="{'class1': client.auditorGroup,  'class2': !client.auditorGroup}"></<div>
```

Comment: can't i use ngStyle?

Comment: sure you can but you gotta use inbuit style prop's like `background-color` etc  ex: `[ngStyle]="{'color': client.auditorGroup ? 'red' : 'green' }` . i prefer ngClass over ngStyle .

Comment: I have used this code but there is no change in table :

Comment: <td *ngIf="!client.auditorGroup" [ngStyle]="{'titleStyles': client.auditorGroup,  'oldStyles1': !client.auditorGroup}">{{client.selectionId}}</td>

Comment: well it wont ngStyle looks for either inbuild style prop's or custom . `titleStyles` will not be understood by ngStyle.

Comment: i have added this line in component.ts file  public titleStyles={
   color:"red"
 }

  public oldStyles1={
   color:"blue"
 }

Comment: thnks it works when i use ngClass but i m still confusw why it is not working for ngStyle?

Comment: for ngStyle you can do based on a function return like @Bazinga suggested .

Comment: @ashwinkarki check my answer